# more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression @ pgadmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

So I wrote this code ,

```
SELECT 
    citizen_id, family_card_id, 
    (SELECT name FROM citizen WHERE clan_id = 6) AS nama, 
    (SELECT gender FROM citizen WHERE clan_id = 6) AS gender 
FROM 
    fcn_citizen;
```

and the output is...

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thank you for answering ^^

Comment: Because `subquery` only return 1 row.. Gave the sample data and the expected output..

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious.  Is there something you don't understand about it?  On the other hand, your data is not obvious.  Sample data and desired results  help.

Answer (score 0):

This is only my guessing.. Perhaps this will work..

```
SELECT 
     fcn_citizen.citizen_id, fcn_citizen.family_card_id,
     Citizen.name as nama, Citizen.gender as gender 
FROM 
     fcn_citizen
     Inner Join Citizen on fcn_Citizen.Citizen_ID = Citizen.Citizen_ID
                        And Citizen.Clan_ID = 6;
```

If you want to use `subquery` you must do `aggregate` or `limit`.. Because `subquery` only `return 1 row` like the error you show. So `Join` will do better in your case.. You can read here for [*Join Documentation*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/tutorial-join.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think SELECT name FROM citizen where clan_id = 6, is returning more than 1 row. Citizen table may have multiple records for clan_id=6. 
If you use a subquery in select it must also return just one row, and you probably have more than 1.